# Prove that integrals are equal

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How to prove following equation? $$2\int_0^\pi xf(\sin x)dx = \pi\int_0^\pi f(\sin x)dx$$

Comment: WHat is $\;f\;$ ? Continuous, differentiable, Riemann integrable...?

Comment: @Joanpemo: that does not really matter. If both the LHS and the RHS make sense (with some definition of $\int$), they are equal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\sin(x)=\sin(\pi -x)$, hence:
$$ 2\int_{0}^{\pi}x\,f(\sin x)\,dx=\int_{0}^{\pi}x\,f(\sin x)\,dx+\int_{0}^{\pi}(\pi -x)f(\sin(\pi-x))\,dx = \int_{0}^{\pi} \pi\,f(\sin x)\,dx.$$

Comment: Why the downvote?